# Getting change of time without polling

Tags: c++, c, linux, time

I want to refresh and have control of time interval changes. Most people only have an infinite loop constantly polling the time from time.h and wasting cycles. There is a way to get clock changes without disturbing too much the system? I am using c/c++ and really want to learn how to do this manually only using linux libraries. Most programs need the notion of time.

I want to be notified of system clock updates. I am trying to do a scientific app that responds in real time. Sleep() and thing like that only let me specify a time delay starting from the execution of that statemen. Localtime() and string returning times from the c header only give me the specific time when was executed. If I use it this time is too late, it had elapsed too many nanoseconds.

Comment: You want to do something periodically, or you want to be notified of updates to the system clock?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man pages to understand how to use the system calls [gettimeofday(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), [setitimer(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setitimer.2.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), [timer_create(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) etc... and library functions (`strftime`, `localtime`, ...) related to time.

If you want to code an application recieving timer events, learn about timers and e.g. `SIGALRM` signal. Read first [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html)

But you really should read e.g. [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) and understand what are [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

You might want to use [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) for polling or for waiting.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach that's also portable and compatible with most other tasks is `select`.  It sleeps until a certain amount of time elapses or a file becomes ready for I/O, which gives you a way to update the task list before the next task occurs.  If you don't need interruption capability, you can just use `sleep` (or `usleep`).

Comment: I would recommend today the `poll` syscall instead of `select` (because the `fd_set` is limited in size).